How to create a Community Edition database using Neo4j Desktop?
All databases created by Neo4j Desktop are in Enterprise Edition. How can I choose Community Edition instead?
Below is the screenshot of the software. Whatever version is chosen, the Enterprise Edition is always used.

Did I miss something? Or it is not possible to use Community Edition via Neo4j Desktop at all?

Neo4j Desktop is is designed to help people work with Neo4j EE. To quote the docs:

Neo4j Desktop is free to download and includes a Neo4j Enterprise
Edition Developer license. This gives you access to all the
capabilities and features of Neo4j Enterprise Edition ...

Although Neo4j Desktop does not help you install Neo4j Community Edition instances, you can still use it to work with an already-installed Neo4j CE instance by connecting to it via a Remote connection.

That is really unfortunate that we cannot use CE versions with Neo4j Desktop. Thank you for your answer.

As my answer mentioned, you can use CE with the Desktop. You just cannot install CE using the Desktop.

Yeah, but "use CE with the Desktop" is no better than just using the web browser. Other features like creating database dumps, or adding files to import/ folder cannot be done with Desktop via Remote Connection.
